# Is 60 to 100 hard faults per second normal?

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance

When I monitor my computer's memory usage in Resource Manager, I see that I constantly get between 60 and 100 hard faults.

Is this normal?

Or is that hard fault graph ideally supposed to be flat at 0?

I run Windows 7 and I have 4GB RAM.

Comment: *I see that I constantly get between 60 and 100 hard faults.* Do you mean spikes between 60 and 100 or is the graph between 60 and 100 all the time?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suppose that it can be normal considering the amount of RAM you have.

The more RAM you have, the fewer hard faults you should see.

Comment: Thanks Pieter :)   So more RAM sounds like a good idea?  Think Hard faults is the deciding factor?

Comment: More memory is a good idea. What you might be seeing is programs starting up which is causing you to see spikes in your graph.

Comment: I figured out what was going wrong. 60-100 HF/s was abnormal. Some stray SoapUI java processes were running and was absolutely chewing my memory. HF/s now averages between 0 and 5. MUUUUCH better.

Comment: Probably need a slightly more nuanced answer -- if you're trying to do a lot with a little RAM, certainly you might have a ton of hard faults, but as willem notes, that "normal" isn't "optimal". I'm going to guess that if you're at 100 faults/sec hours after booting, you need more memory -- or you need to stop trying to do what you're doing on that box.

Answer (score 19):

Memory Hard Faults have nothing to do with the 'brand' or 'quality' of the memory. It means that the software has requested an address and the page where it resides isn't still in main memory. Usually it has been swapped to virtual memory, (hard drive or SSD) and the OS will swap it back from virtual memory to physical memory. If you are getting massive amounts of hard faults/sec, it is usually due to too little RAM

Comment: Hi! Firstly, sorry for my intromission, but I have 16GB in my PC and I'm experiencing more than 1500 page faults. The system runs fine, I'm not having any bsod, but this number concerned me. Should I worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

On my 2009 laptop with 3GB of RAM there are usually 0-20 hard faults per/sec while playing a game, processing a video, etc. It could be that certain kinds of RAM like ECC or certain brand qualities.